# jquery class selector yields unusable id

Tags: javascript, jquery, selector

I am getting an id that is not addressable by jquery ("#"+id).something .
At document start I have a :

```
var g_justClicked = '';
  $.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend:function(event){
      if(g_justClicked) {
        console.log('g_justClicked='+g_justClicked+' tagName='+$('#'+g_justClicked).tagName);
      };
      var wOffset = $('#'+g_justClicked).offset(); 
      $('#loading').show();
      },
      complete:function(){
        $('#loading').hide();
      }
     });
```

At document end I have another script (all elements with class spinner should set the global variable 'g_justClicked'):

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $('.spinner').click(function() { 
          g_justClicked = $(this).attr('id');
          console.log('.spinner.click:  g_justClicked='+g_justClicked);
      });
```

This works fine, the variable is set and displayed correctly in ajaxSetup.

BUT: referencing it in tagName=  or in wOffset =  with

```
$('#'+g_justClicked).
```

results in 
"TypeError: wOffset/tagName is undefined"

Note: all ids start with several characters, t.e. "boxshow12345" is a typical id.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Because you're declaring your variable inside a closure it looks like. It's undefined because you define it only in the ajaxSetup. Declare your variables outside of the ajax call and then you should be able to reference them later. Just like you did with var g_justClicked = ''; at the start.

Comment: Where you are accessing `tagName` and `wOffset`?

Answer (score 0):

I think was able to reproduce your scenario here: https://jsfiddle.net/mrlew/qvvnjjxn/3/

The `undefined` in your `console.log` is because you're accessing an inexistent jQuery property: `.tagName`. This property is only available to native [HTML Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/tagName).

To retrieve the tag name from a jQuery Object, you should use: `.prop("tagName")`, or access the property accessing the native element with `$('#'+g_justClicked)[0].tagName`

So, if you change

```
console.log('g_justClicked='+g_justClicked+' tagName='+$('#'+g_justClicked).tagName);
```

to:

```
console.log('g_justClicked='+g_justClicked+' tagName='+$('#'+g_justClicked).prop("tagName"));
```

Will successfully log: `g_justClicked=boxshow12345 tagName=BUTTON`, as expected.

**Note:** In order to your logic work, you have to click `.spinner` first.

Comment: Thank you; I tried, but it doesn't work. See details in answers to @Nikolay Ermakov .

Comment: @Beckermint can you be more specific what didn't work? have you tryied the fiddle above? what was the expeced behavior? it runs without error

Comment: OK1:  @mrlew  Answer: I tried your .prop appoach, but still got "undefined". Now back to the roots:
The goal is to get the id of any element of class spinner that was clicked to modify the busy indicators position, while ajax is running. Newly I am back to my original approach, without global variable and parameter passing:

Comment: OK2:  
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $('.spinner').click(function() { 
        _setupAjax();
        });
    });

which works, and:

Comment: OK3: 
    function _setupAjax() {
        $.ajaxSetup({
            beforeSend: function() {
               $('#loading').show();
               wJustClicked = $(this).attr('id');   ///  <- that doesnt work!
               console.log("_setupAjax  wJustClicked="+wJustClicked);
               console.log('_setupAjax  tagName=' + $('#' + wJustClicked).prop("tagName"));
               ....defining css based on id (no problem)..

which yields "undefined" twice. 
I tried so many ways to get that f.... id.

Comment: @Beckermint in the fiddle, `.prop` worked as expected. Maybe it's something else on your code. Do you mind post somewhere your full code? github repo, maybe. So, I can give a look.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your ajax setup runs regardless of whatever you do in the `click` handler, and it runs before you even setup that handler. The initial value for `g_justClicked` is empty string, and this is what it tries to access in `$('#'+g_justClicked)`, hence the error.

If you want to click the spinner and then pass the id to the `beforeSend`, do it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.spinner').click(function() {
        var g_justClicked = this.id;  //simplify this a bit
        console.log('.spinner.click:  g_justClicked=' + g_justClicked);
        // call ajax
        _setupAjax( g_justClicked );
    });
});

function _setupAjax(g_justClicked) {
    $.ajaxSetup({
        beforeSend: function(event) {
            if (g_justClicked) {
                console.log('g_justClicked=' + g_justClicked + ' tagName=' + $('#' + g_justClicked).tagName);
            };
            var wOffset = $('#' + g_justClicked).offset();
            $('#loading').show();
        },
        complete: function() {
            $('#loading').hide();
        }
    });
}
```

**UPDATE**

If you don't want a separate function, just move your ajax setup into the click handler:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.spinner').click(function() {
        var g_justClicked = this.id;  //simplify this a bit
        console.log('.spinner.click:  g_justClicked=' + g_justClicked);

        // call ajax setup
        $.ajaxSetup({
            beforeSend: function(event) {
                if (g_justClicked) {
                    console.log('g_justClicked=' + g_justClicked + ' tagName=' + $('#' + g_justClicked).tagName);
                };
                var wOffset = $('#' + g_justClicked).offset();
                $('#loading').show();
            },
            complete: function() {
                $('#loading').hide();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you both!  I always knew that it is a timing problem, but not how to manage it. What I do not understand in @Nikolay Ermakov solution is: your defining a function _setupAjax. But were is it triggered / called?

Comment: Feel free to suggest another solution without a separate function, where directly after beforeSend: the id of the last clicked element is picked, but only if its class is "spinner" and regardless of the element tag, that in my case may be SPAN, DIV and IMG.

Comment: Hi there!  I moved the function content into the click handler, if you like it better. It will be triggered if any element with class `spinner` was clicked.

Comment: Thanx, tried both, but it doesn't work for me. Now state of the art is: 1. a <script> snipplet in <head> only initilaizing g_justClicked ="".  2. put the script in a .js-File.  3. document. ready still at the end of the document:

    console.log('Document ready !!');
    $('.spinner').click(function() { 
       g_justClicked = $(this).attr('id');
      console.log('.spinner.click:  g_justClicked='+g_justClicked);
      _setupAjax( g_justClicked );
    });

Comment: now I have removed a) the initialization in the head script, because no longer needed, and b) the "event" in the brackets of beforeSend, because it was never used. Result: the same.
Eventually I am misleading you all. My original intention was to make the id-getting directly after beforeSend. But non of my approaches work, only that complicated one by using an external function. So if you have an idea how to catch ANY triggering element's id from there, I will be satisfied.

Comment: What do you mean - after `beforeSend` ? When you make an ajax call ?

Comment: "after" means only the program line, not execution sequences of modules

Answer (score 0):

OK @mrlew. 
Answer: I tried your .prop appoach, but still got "undefined". Now back to the roots:
The goal is to get the id of any element that was clicked to modify the busy indicators position, while ajax is running. Newly I am back to my original approach, without global variable and parameter passing:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.spinner').click(function() { 
    _setupAjax();
    });
});
```

which works, and:

```
function _setupAjax() {
    $.ajaxSetup({
        beforeSend: function() {
           $('#loading').show();
           wJustClicked = $(this).attr('id');   ///  <- that doesnt work!
           console.log("_setupAjax  wJustClicked="+wJustClicked);
           console.log('_setupAjax  tagName=' + $('#' + wJustClicked).prop("tagName"));
           ....defining css based on id (no problem)..
```

which yields "undefined" twice. I tried so many ways to get that f.... id.

Answer (score 0):

@mrlew
thanks a lot for your help. Meanwhile I found the solution. All trouble came from a timing problem. Here is what works (for all DIV, SPAN and IMG of class=spinner and having an id:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  _setupAjax();
  $('.spinner').click(function() { 
      wJustClicked = $(this).attr('id'); 
      if(wJustClicked == null) alert('Id missing on item clicked');
      console.log('.spinner.click!  id='+wJustClicked);
      var wOffset = $('#' + wJustClicked).offset();
      var xPos = Math.round(wOffset.left) + 8;
      var yPos = Math.round(wOffset.top) + 4;
      console.log(wJustClicked+' offset  left='+wOffset.left+' top='+wOffset.top+' xPos='+xPos+' yPos='+yPos);
      wDiv = 'loading';
      $('#'+wDiv).css('left',xPos);
      $('#'+wDiv).css('top',yPos);
  });
```

and the js function:

```
function _setupAjax() {
    $.ajaxSetup({
        beforeSend: function() {
            $('#loading').show();
        },
        complete: function() {
            $('#loading').hide();
        }
    });
}
```

A strange thing remained (I have firebug installed), which I have solved with Math.round: the x and y position come overdetailed like  170.5134577 and 434.8768664 ?!?
I can live with that. But where does this pseudo precision come from?
Again thanks a lot to keep my hope upright.